# Linkify "Migration Statistics" for >10k users

Tags: feature-request, migration, 10k-tools, statistics, migrated-questions

I was recently looking at the [Migration Stats for Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (10k view).  (I wanted to see what other sites thought of as good/bad migrations.)

I like the statistics view since it shows me a rough idea of how good or bad we are at migrating to a particular site.  However, it's hard to "drill down" and look only at the questions sent to a particular site.

For instance, if I want to see which questions we sent to Physics in the last 90 days and were accepted vs. rejected, I can't do so (at least, from this view).  Sure, I can see a long list of *every* question that was migrated to/from the site in the here/away/rejected tabs, but they aren't organized by source/destination site (which is useful).  The ability to access this information is important for maintaining good "inter-site" relations; if I can see what questions were migrated to physics *and rejected,* I can improve over time.

**The request:** Turn the `[site] -> [site]` icons on the Stats page into links to a listing of the questions to which they are referring, organized by rejected/accepted.  Specifically, if I clicked `[MathOverflow] -> [Math.SE]` below, I'd be taken to a page listing the 66 questions that MathOverflow sent to Math.SE.  There would be two columns (or two collapsible rows) on this page: accepted migrations and rejected migrations.

[image: migrations]

(I wasn't sure if I'm not supposed to share the statistics--I did have to get 10k to see them to begin with--so I blacked out the "% rejected," which I'd guess to be the most "sensitive" information.)